# Limiting recursive 'aws s3 ls' searches by number of items in the folder

Tags: ls, recursive, aws, amazon-s3

Here's the scenario:

I need to recursively search through tons and tons of folders and subfolders and spit out the results to a log file using the ls command, BUT, I need to stop searching a folder if it has more than 10~ objects? The reason being is once I have a sample of 10 items in a folder, I know what's in the folder, and since some folders contain tens of thousands of results, this will save lots of time.

Why are you limited to 'ls'?
Because I am searching S3, using the command `aws s3 ls`. The command `aws s3 ls --summarize --recursive` does what I need, I just now need a way to limit the search based on the number of items in a folder.

I have tried using aws s3api list-buckets & list-objects and so forth, but even with the --max-values tag it doesn't do what I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not really `ls` is it.

Answer (score 1):

roaima is correct; "aws s3 ls" is named that way so people know the kind of work it does (list files). It's not really the ls command and just tries to behave the same at a very, very surface level.

I believe the best way to do what you want would be to write a script using the boto3 API; s3.client.list_objects() has a MaxKeys argument that you can use to limit retrievals within a path.